# How can I add a new word before last three lines in a string in swift?

Tags: swift, algorithm, slice

How can I add a new word before last three lines in a string in swift, so that string would convert from this:

```
"Who composed the\n
popular song "Aati Kya\n
Khandala" from 'Ghulam"?\n
Jatin- Lalit\n
Abhijeet\n
Aamir Khan"
```

To this:

```
"Who composed the\n
popular song "Aati Kya\n
Khandala" from 'Ghulam"?\n
sagarduhanishere\n
Jatin- Lalit\n
Abhijeet\n
Aamir Khan"
```

Comment: Use `components(separatedBy:)` to transform that `String` into an `Array`, then insert your new string wherever you need it, and transform it back into a `String`?

Comment: can you please write me the code to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted answer works fine for short strings. For better space (and time) complexity, you can avoid unnecessarily splitting the string and rejoining all the elements of an array, this way :

Let's start with this text :

```
let text = """
Who composed the
popular song "Aati Kya
Khandala" from 'Ghulam"?
Jatin- Lalit
Abhijeet
Aamir Khan
"""
```

The result will be stored in this variable :

```
var result = ""
```

With the code belo, we look for the third `\n` starting from the end of original string:

```
let start = text.startIndex
let end = text.endIndex
var index = text.index(end, offsetBy: -1)
var linesToGo = 3

while start < index  {
    if text[index] == "\n" {
        linesToGo -= 1
    }
    if linesToGo == 0 {
        index = text.index(index, offsetBy: 1)
        result = text[start..<index] + "sagarduhanishere\n" + text[index..<end]
        break
    }
    index = text.index(index, offsetBy: -1)
}
```

And then we can check if we have found 3 lines or not

```
if linesToGo != 0 {
    fatalError("More lines needed")
}
```

Then print the result or use it in your code :

```
print(result)
```

which outputs :

> ```
> Who composed the
> popular song "Aati Kya
> Khandala" from 'Ghulam"?
> sagarduhanishere
> Jatin- Lalit
> Abhijeet
> Aamir Khan
> ```

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you have string like this

```
let string = """
    "Who composed the
    popular song "Aati Kya
    Khandala" from 'Ghulam"?
    Jatin- Lalit
    Abhijeet
    Aamir Khan"
"""
```

or like this

```
let string = """
    "Who composed the\npopular song "Aati Kya\nKhandala" from 'Ghulam"?\nJatin- Lalit\nAbhijeet\nAamir Khan"
"""
```

So, first separate your string to an array of strings

```
var separated = string.components(separatedBy: "\n")
```

then insert new string at index where you need to

```
separated.insert("sagarduhanishere", at: separated.endIndex - 3)
```

and then just join this array back to one string

```
let joined = separated.joined(separator: "\n")
```

---

```
var separated = string.components(separatedBy: "\n")
separated.insert("sagarduhanishere", at: separated.endIndex - 3)
let joined = separated.joined(separator: "\n")
print(joined)
```

> `"Who composed the
>   popular song "Aati Kya
>   Khandala" from 'Ghulam"?
>   sagarduhanishere
>   Jatin- Lalit
>   Abhijeet
>   Aamir Khan"`

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Regex way. It's another choice.

```
        let s = """
        Who composed the
        popular song "Aati Kya
        Khandala" from 'Ghulam"?
        Jatin- Lalit
        Abhijeet
        Aamir Khan
        """

        let replaceString = "sagarduhanishere"

        let nextS = s.replacingOccurrences(of: "(\n.*){3}$", with: "\n\(replaceString)$0", options: .regularExpression  , range: nil)

        print(nextS)
```